# how to determine the domain of this function: $\sqrt{(\sin(x))^2 + \sin x}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

let $x$ be in this interval: $[0, 2\pi]$. the exercise's request is to find the domain of this function:$$\sqrt{(\sin(x))^2 + \sin x}$$

Here's my attempt to solve it:

1. I found the domain of the square root: $$(sin (x))^2 + \sin x \geq 0$$
   In this case, I've found that $$\sin x \ge 0 $$ and that: $$\sin x \ge -1 $$

in the trigonometric circle, I have found that the set of solution is only the 4th quadrant, since the sin of -1 is $3/2\pi$ (270 degree).

Is that correct?

Comment: Instead of ($\sin(x)\ge 0$ and $\sin(x)\ge -1$), don't you want to say that ($\sin(x) \ge 0$ or $\sin(x) \le -1$)?

Comment: the sign of the inequality doesn't change, since the argument of a square root function must be greater than or equal to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is perhaps a better way to approach,  consider:

$$ f= \sin^2 x + \sin x$$

Now, we can see there are zero set for this function: $ \sin x = \{0,-1 \}$, in the interval $[0, 2 \pi]$ the zero set in terms of 'x' : $\{0, \pi, \frac{ 3 \pi}{2} \}$. Hence, the domain of $x$ in which the function is greater than zero and also belongining the original domain constrained is given by:

$$ \left[ 0 , \pi \right] \cup \left[ \frac{3 \pi}{2} , 2 \pi\right]$$

**Explanation:**

The function 'sign flips' whenever it hits a root, so we can partition the given domain  based on root as as:

$$ \left[ 0, \pi \right] \cup \left[ \pi, \frac{ 3 \pi}{2} \right] \cup \left[ \frac{3 \pi}{2} , 2 \pi \right]$$

Now since in the first domain the function is positive, the second it will be negative and third it will be positive again. Hence, the final answer is given by:

$$ \left[ 0, \pi \right] \cup \left[ \frac{ 3\pi}{2} , 2\pi \right]$$

---

#### Edit

Oops! The function above is slightly more complicated than a regular quadratic in the sense that a zero doesn't correspond exactly as a sign flip!

As correctly pointed out by the @The 2nd, the function retain's it's negative sign even after the zero $ \frac{3 \pi}{2}$ , hence the whole domain of $x$ values greater than $ \frac{3 \pi}{2}$ is neglected. But, there is still one more root to consider, that is the one at $ x = 2 \pi$

Hence, the final answer is given by:

$$ \left[ 0 , \pi \right] \cup \left[ \frac{ 3 \pi}{2} \right] \cup \left[ 2 \pi \right]$$

Comment: why didn't you consider the domain of the square root (greater than or equal to zero)?

Comment: Yeah I did that in second step, that's why I intersected the allowed domain with the part of domain where function is positive. That's why we went from $ [0, 2 \pi ]$ to $ [ 0 , \pi ] U [ 3pi/2, 2pi]$

Comment: $\frac{7\pi}{4} \in \left[ \frac{ 3\pi}{2} , 2\pi \right]$, but $(\sin(\frac{7\pi}{4}))^2 + \sin \frac{7\pi}{4} < 0$

Comment: Hmm good catch, now what exactly went wrong

Comment: Pl. check the edit @GabrielBurzacchini

Comment: This answer (after Edit) is wrong and should not be accepted.

Comment: @YvesDaoust perhaps it is so, but could you share why you think it is wrong?

Comment: Also $2\pi$ is a solution as $\sin(0) = \sin(2\pi)$:)

Comment: Ah, thank you @The2nd

Answer (score 4):

Let $t = \sin x \,\, (-1 \leq t \leq 1)$

The domain of the function will become:

$$t^2 + t \geq 0$$

$$\implies t \in (-\infty, -1] \cup [0, +\infty)$$

But $-1 \leq t \leq 1 \implies t = -1$ or $0 \leq t \leq 1$

- $t = -1 \implies \sin x = -1 \implies x = -\dfrac{\pi}{2} + k2\pi \implies x = \dfrac{3\pi}{2}$ (since $x \in [0, 2\pi]$)
- $0 \leq t \leq 1 \implies 0 \leq \sin x \leq 1 \implies x \in [0, \pi] \cup \{2\pi\}$

Therefore, the domain is:

$$D = [0, \pi] \cup \left\{\dfrac{3\pi}{2}, 2\pi \right\}$$

Comment: @Buraian As you let $t = \sin x$, you can consider it like a regular quadratic, as long as you care about the interval of that quadratic $(-1 \leq t \leq 1)$
Also $\left\{\frac{3\pi}{2}, 2\pi \right\}$ is not an interval, but rather than 2 distinct values

Comment: Misread that oops, good catch. @The 2nd

Comment: @Buraian You're welcome:D

Answer (score 1):

What if $\sin x(\sin x+1)=0?$

Else  we need $\sin x(\sin x+1)>0$

If $\sin x>0,\sin x+1>0\iff\sin x>-1\implies \sin x>$ max$(0,-1)$

$\implies2n\pi\le x\le2n\pi+\pi$

What if $\sin x<0?$

Comment: but the argument of the square root must be positive or equal to zero, why did you put the negative sign?

Comment: @GabrielBurzacchini, Thanks for your observation

Answer (score 1):

We must have

$$\sin x(\sin x+1)\ge0.$$

As $$\sin x+1\ge0$$ is always true, we seem to be left with

$$\sin x\ge 0.$$

But there is a trap*: when $$\sin x+1=0$$ the sign of $\sin x$ is irrelevant and finally $$x\in[0,\pi]\cup\left\{\frac{3\pi}2,2\pi\right\}.$$

*Credit to Buraian.

---

After the fact, a systematic solution is

$$\sin x>0\lor\sin x=0\lor\sin x=-1,$$

$$x\in(0,\pi)\cup\{0,\pi,2\pi\}\cup\left\{\frac\pi2,\frac{3\pi}2\right\}.$$

Comment: This too is wrong, you missed the root at $ \frac{ 3 \pi }{2}$

Comment: @Buraian: right, fixing.